# upsampling for regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

Let us say I have a regression problem with on dependent variable y and a factor independent variable X with 3 levels x1, x2 and x3 (Y ~ X). x1 has 25 sample and x2 + x3 have 150 respectively.

Is it possible to use upsampling methods used for classification problems to obtain more samples for x1? Basically making Y an independent variable and  x1 the class with the low priors whilts lumping the rest together. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Maybe others can make sense of this, but I lack the understanding of what you might mean by "upsampling" and "making Y an independent variable" to do so.  It sounds like you're hoping to create new data out of old, but that's not possible: all you can hope for is either (a) to improve your statistical procedure and/or (b) to collect more data.  Perhaps you could provide a small simple example of what you have in mind?

Comment: I appreciate your comment @whuber and I love your other contributions here. However, I think my request is fairly clear and one does not always have the luxury of collecting more samples. SMOTE et al. are upsampling methods used quite often in classification contexts.

Comment: Because I haven't a clue what you are asking about, despite understanding something about classification and over- and under-sampling, take me as preliminary evidence that your question would benefit from clarification.

Comment: @whuber - is suggest you have a look at SMOTE to see how this can be used for upsampling.

Comment: I did that last week, but your question hasn't become any clearer in the meantime.